# Transparent proxy improvement using haproxy load balancer?

Tags: tails, whonix, transparent-proxy, proxy, stream-isolation

I want to know if isn't a good idea to use many instances of Tor and load balancing them through haproxy.
I've tested here.. I ran 20 Tor instances (20 socks5 ports) and load balanced them through haproxy. Haproxy give me one socks5 port, e.g: 9080, and each time a connection goes through that port, i had a different Tor IP address. I also set up torrc `MaxCircuitDirtness` to 180s (this changed the IP address of each Tor instance 3 in 3 minutes).
In one hour, I received 156 different IPs (using a loop calling http://ipecho.net/plain on terminal).
I saw people using this to run web crawling codes.
Isn't that a good a idea to use on a transparent proxy (or on a system wide proxy) to improve stream isolation?

Answer (score 1):

It's questionable whether it's an improvement to the existing way that a client generates certificates. Your HAProxy is basically converting your configuration into an pre-2014 Tor circuit building process because it will likely choose a separate entryguard for each circuit. This makes it statistically less secure which is why they switched to a semi-persistent entryguard model.

I assume that you're getting some bandwidth improvements just because it's a different way of connecting to Tor but Tor does attempt to generate a bunch of streams for you already. From this perspective, it is already load balancing (and it's much smarter at it than HAproxy FWIW).

A better way to do what you're doing is to learn how to manually access the circuits that are pre-build and attach your streams one by one so that a single stream can take a single circuit path without affecting speed. So yeah, it works fine, just a little ham fisted.